# What is android_compat_build_artifacts of poky in yocto

Tags: android, yocto

I know that `poky` is the `yocto` project reference build system.

I've learnt that, one can introduce a `Android` component to yocto. 
And keep the `Android.mk` as the `Makefile`. It strange to me, since I always use `autotools` `configure.ac` and `Makefile.am` to introduce new components in `yocto`.

I've seen folder named `android_compat_build_artifacts` under my `poky/build/` directory. So is there a android compatible way to deal with `Android.mk` directly in yocto projects ? Any reference of it ?

Thank You

Comment: Well, `android_compat_build_artifacts` is nothing that normally is generated. Thus, you have something locally. To start with, give us all your layers and their versions. (This can be taken by copying the output  from bitbake, until it starts parsing recipes).

Comment: @Alan did you ever figure it out?

Comment: @user3325563 I think this is making android makefiles `Android.mk` workable in yocto.